# How can I run adb command from the same device?

Tags: usb, android, adb

Normally you have your Android device with adbd running on it. You connect the device with your pc for example using usb cable (with dev mode on) and you can see the device and run specific adb commands towards this device.

What I want to do is to install Android app which will ship adb compiled for arm and I want to run exactly the same command but using adb client from the apk this time. I want to run Java process which will launch shell command which should run desired adb command.

The problem is that the installed adb doesn't see its counterpart (adbd).

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Adb over tcpip, directed at local host, on the unconventional port of your choosing?
Not that I know for certain that it would work...
It would be my first attempt at a solution though.
Perhaps using the common workaround of the day... 
Use a VPN to trick adb into thinking it's not on the same device.
Also take a look at the kadb and kfastboot installation zip.
As I recall, the binaries were renamed to avoid some conflict with adbd being on the same device.